# How can I change this code to upload multiple files?

Tags: php, file-upload

Here I am uploading single file to the database and I used longblob, how can I change this code to upload multiple files to database with same id and also I can able to download more than one uploaded files for the same id in download option. Can anyone please help me?

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
        // Make sure the file was sent without errors
        if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {
            // Connect to the database
            $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '12345', 'documentksrsac');
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            // Gather all required data
            //$project_name = $_POST["pname"];
             //$project_name = $dbLink->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['project_name']));
            // $project_name =real_escape_string(['uploaded_file']['project_name']);
            $name = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
            $mime = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']);
            $data = $dbLink->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
            $size = intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']);

            // Create the SQL query
            $query = "
                INSERT INTO `fileupload1` (
                    `name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`
                )
                VALUES (
                  '{$name}', '{$mime}', {$size}, '{$data}'
                )";

            // Execute the query
            $result = $dbLink->query($query);

            // Check if it was successfull
            if($result) {
                echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
            }
            else {
                echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file'
                   . "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'An error accured while the file was being uploaded. '
               . 'Error code: '. intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']);
        }

        // Close the mysql connection
        $dbLink->close();
    }
    else {
        echo 'Error! A file was not sent!';
    }


    // close connection
    //mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple Image uploading I am using given code:-

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="img[]" >
<input type="file" name="img[]" >
<input type="file"  name="img[]" >
<input type="file"  name="img[]" >
<button type="submit" name="save" >Submit</button>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
$img_name=$_FILES['img']['name'];
$img_type=$_FILES['img']['type'];
$img_temp_name=$_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
$img_size=$_FILES['img']['size'];
$count=count($img_name);
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
$name=$img_name[$i];
$type=$img_type[$i];
$temp_name=$img_temp_name[$i];
$size=$img_size[$i];
$query = "INSERT INTO `fileupload1` (`name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`)VALUES ('{$name}', '{$type}', {$temp_name}, '{$size}')";
$result = $dbLink->query($query);
 }
}
```